# Failed to upload action package to AOG (preview)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm getting so many errors trying to create non-english AoG projects with Dialogflow.

The error is:

```
Failed to upload action package to AOG (preview)
Request contains an invalid argument.
Locale pt-br was selected but the language pt-BR has not been selected.
```

I did this steps in Dialogflow:

1. Clicked at create new agent
2. Set default language to Portuguese(brazilian) - pt-br
3. Clicked at create button
4. After working progress, I did this path Integration -> Google Assistant -> Test
5. The AoG page did not open and I got the error above.

Does someone know how to fix this issues?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have an existing Actions on Google project with the same language?

I usually create the AoG project first (when creating non-English Actions) and then I create the Dialogflow agent by going under Actions -> Build -> Custom. When you select the same language in Dialogflow, and click create it should work.

Comment: Hi, yes I did and all my non-english projects stopped working last week with this bug. I'll try your approach, thank you.

Comment: Let me know how it goes please. I'll try to reproduce the bug to understand what goes wrong when I get the chance.

Comment: Did not work. I sent an email to Google Support and they said it's a known bug and they forward to Engineering Team to conduct further investigation. I'll let you know if something change. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to inform me.

Comment: There is a issue opened about this on Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123347859. You can to star it for updates. I'm waiting for the resolution of this problem too.

Comment: everything is ok now